# Where is log for CGI Errors in IIS

Tags: iis, cgi, administration

I use IIS to run CGI scripts written on python (hgweb.cgi).

But if something goes wrong IIS doesn't provide detailed information. It just writes in log:

2018-10-20 10:14:52 W3SVC1 ::1 POST /hgweb.cgi/ cmd=unbundle 9000 - ::1 mercurial/proto-1.0+(Mercurial+4.1.3) - localhost:9000 502 2 1 295

Error 502. But why it was happened it doesn't write.
I belive this error is detailed in stderr output of python script, but where to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that iis logging is enable.
If it's not enabled, you can see below link to find out:

[How to enable logging in Internet Information Services (IIS)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313437/how-to-enable-logging-in-internet-information-services-iis)

Comment: By that, you can specify log file address.

Comment: Logs are enabled. But where is stderr output of scripts?

Comment: Which version of IIS do you use?

Comment: Also you can change extension and path of log file from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile/#how-to

Answer (score 0):

My solution is: https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/node246.html
I redirected stderr to stdout and made try catch in script.
This looks like a hack, but it works...